# setBackgroundColor causes issues on canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

Is it possible to set transparent view, using something other than the code below?

```
this.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Because this one always screws my canvas drawing (for example, objects on it don't move when I change their coords).

Answer (score 0):

If you are drawing on canvas use canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); Then you can draw whatever you want over it.